# Invisible spin allowed transitions in Tanabe-Sugano diagrams

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, uv-vis-spectroscopy

In class we are looking at Tanabe-Sugano diagrams, more concretely at transitions for a d<sup>2</sup> complex. [image: d2 tanabe-sugano diagram]

I understand that the only spin allowed transitions are those that have a triplet state, therefore that there are 3 spin allowed transitions

<sup>3</sup>T<sub>1g</sub> (P) <- <sup>3</sup>T<sub>1g</sub> (F)

<sup>3</sup>A<sub>2g</sub> (F) <- <sup>3</sup>T<sub>1g</sub> (F)

<sup>3</sup>T<sub>2g</sub> (F) <- <sup>3</sup>T<sub>1g</sub> (F)

These can be seen in the diagram. In addition, were are given the orbital occupancies for each energetic state some of which I have attached for clarity.

[image]

From the  occupancy image, it can be seen that the <sup>3</sup>A<sub>2g</sub> state corresponds to both d electrons being in the high energy e<sub>g</sub> orbitals. Hence my question is what process can lead to both electrons being in such an excited state? Is it possible for a photon to excite both electrons at the time? Which I had never heard of before, or is it that in order to achieve the <sup>3</sup>A<sub>2g</sub> excited state, 2 photons need to be absorbed in rapid succession, going through an intermediate excited state?

If two photons need to be absorbed does that effectively make the <sup>3</sup>A<sub>2g</sub> state "impossible" to reach and thus the absorption band isn't seen?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is better to imagine as the energy is absorbed by the whole system not by individual electrons. Two-electron excitations exist (simultaneous, not just one by one).

Comment: Two photon absorption is well known using short pulsed lasers as high flux is needed, but only on electron is promoted. (Different selection rules also apply) To get two electrons excited will need two absorptions one after the other, probably at different energies, so v. v. hard to achieve in practice  as excited species always decay rapidly back to the ground state. In a thought experiment, of course, you may be able to excite an excited state again to reach the state you want.